# Is there a word that means boring and fun at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m a Junior in High School and I’m trying to answer a question for a discussion board and the question is “In ONE WORD, how would you describe this past week?” I’m trying to say that it was both boring and fun at the same time. Is there a word that describes both boring and fun?

Comment: Presumably you mean that the week had boring bits and fun bits rather than stating that the boring bits were fun?

Comment: Yes @KillingTime

Comment: It has to be one word

Comment: No, but your feelings could describe the week as *mixed*.

Comment: *Vacillating, ambivalent, miscellaneous*? Look their meanings up and see which one fits the information you've provided. (I agree with Yosef).

Comment: Those words may be accurate labels for a week that had fun parts and boring parts, but they don't *mean* fun and boring.

Comment: Thank you so much @DecapitatedSoul

Comment: _Mindless_ is how I would describe it.

Comment: I don’t think you can do this in one word. Mind-numbingly frivolous covers the two concepts.